# Populate ListView with Dynamic Array

Tags: android

I have a `EditText` box so a user can input names and then click the *Add* button and the name saves to the array `playerList` and clears the box so another name can be added.

I also have a `ListView` on the same Activity which will then be populated by the names in the `Array` `playerList`. The problem is that the `ListView` dosen't seem to be populated.

So I tried with a defualt set String `teststring` which you can see below and that populates the `ListView` fine. My question is how come it isn't working with the `Array` `playerList` maybe its not saving to the `Array` correctly?

**Update just need `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` adding to refresh the `ListView` Credit to @Lalit Poptani and @Jave**

```
ArrayList<String> playerList = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView listview;
protected String[] teststring = {"Name 1", "Name 2"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.addremove);
ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, teststring);
ListView employeeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.namelistview);
employeeList.setAdapter(adapter);


Button confirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
confirm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
EditText playername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userinput);
String name = playername.getText().toString();
playerList.add(name);
playername.setText("");

}});
```

Comment: have you tried printing the array values i mean playerlist values..???? Is array populating fine..???? if yes then you must call notifyDataSetChnaged() whenever is adapter updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call [`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) after adding new items to make it update with the new data.

> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been
>   changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

Comment: Where abouts should it be called?

Comment: Just after you have updated the list. It basically tells it that it has new items in it.

Comment: so it would be after `playerList.add(name);`

Comment: Cool, but getting the error `The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type ListAdapter` :/

Comment: Ah, you can(should) define it as an ArrayAdapter instead of a ListAdapter: `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(args);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6644/discussion-between-matt-and-jave)

Answer (score 3):

To refresh the ListView after you add new data to it you have to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. This is refresh your ListView will new data.

But in your case you are populating your ListView with String[] so it won't work dynamically you will have to give the size of the `String[]`. So, I will suggest you to populate your ListView with `ArrayList` itself for adding the content dynamically.

```
ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                       (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,playerList);
```

Comment: Heh, answering 4 secs before me :p

Comment: @Lalit Where abouts should that be called?

Comment: Matt in your button when you add data in your arrayList just after that call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: @LalitPoptani Ahh ok so then I would have to convert my `ListAdapter` to `final ListAdapter adapter`

Comment: You can but I will say to declare `ListAdapter adapter`; globally above onCreate.

Comment: @LalitPoptani Answer was correct im just having a chat with Jave if you want to join?

Comment: Sure no problem you can give me the link of chat room or you both can come to my Room [Casual Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1531/casual-chat)

Comment: Link to chats here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6644/discussion-between-matt-and-jave